# Can a Silverlight application use containing HTML styles?

Tags: silverlight, styles

I'm developing a Silverlight 4 app that has to live within an existing ASP/HTML based site, which has its own css stylesheet.  I want the Silverlight app to share the look and feel of its container application, so I'm wondering about the best way to accomplish this.  About the only way I can think of would be to translate the css styles into Silverlight styles (perhaps with an automated tool), but that seems like a lot of work for something that is a pretty common use case.

Is there a better way?  Are there existing tools to make this easier?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this "use case" is as "common" as you think it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Silverlight styles based on the styles of your site is a good idea.  I don't know if there is an automated tool to do this, but your CSS would have to be very long and complex for that to be necessary.

You might consider modifying an existing [Silverlight Theme](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) to match your site.